# PHPExcel integration into Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpexcel

how can I integrate the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) into my Zend app.

My actual folder structure is the following:

```
/application
  controllers
  views  
  etc...
/library
  My
  Zend
  PHPExcel
/public
  index.php
```

I already include 'My' libs by using (in index.php):

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace('My_');
```

Now I also want to use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) inside one of my controllers like:

```
$exc = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('test.xls');
$excelWorksheet = $exc->getActiveSheet();
```

What do I have to do to make it work and get rid of the `Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found` Exception?

Thank you.
-lony

P.S.: A simple `$autoloader->registerNamespace('PHPExcel_');` is not working. I tested it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Place the PHPExcel library into the /library folder, like this:

```
/application
...
/library
    /PHPExcel
    /PHPExcel.php
```

Next, in your application.ini config file, add the following:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "PHPExcel_"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "PHPExcel"
```

That should do it. Autoloader takes care of the rest, and you can just start using the example code to read an Excel file.

**Update**: Added the extra autoloaderNamespace as suggested by commenters

Comment: As described in my question I tried to use `$autoloader->registerNamespace('PHPExcel_');` and it was not working. Your solution only move the setting from the `index.php` to `application.ini`, but it is still not running.

Comment: Do you have the same setup in your /library folder? The base PHPExcel.php file is right under /library, and then the rest of the classes is under /library/PHPExcel.

I implemented this just yesterday, without any problems

Comment: The only problem with this is that it makes adding PHPExcel as an svn:external either difficult (separate external for PHPExcel.php), or impossible.

Comment: So I placed PHPExcel library into the /library folder, added line to ini file and (!) updated my index.php file: 
`set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/PHPExcel'),get_include_path())));`

Comment: I did it this way, but when in the controller I call
$xlsObj = new PHPExcel();
it returns the error Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel' not found in...

Comment: For me the above solution didn't work either, resulting in class not found exception. Adding not only `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "PHPExcel_"` but also `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "PHPExcel"` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution:

> require_once
>   'PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

If somebody has a better one, please keep posting!

@BoltClock: Thanks for updating the Tags.

Comment: Well, from the snippet you posted above your problem is quite obvious, move all of the PHPExcel source one level up, so IOFactory.php is located in library/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php instead of library/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php. That should do the trick (and you can ditch the require_once).

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be in your include path.

If you ever need a custom autoloader for other libraries that don't follow PSR-0, there's this too: [Autoload PhpThumb with Zend Framework](http://blog.montmere.com/2010/12/26/autoload-phpthumb-with-zend-framework/) (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: Hm, looks really like the solution I wanted. I try it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 2 years since the question is asked but it may help someone;
the easiest way ( not the optimal) is to extract the PHPExcel folder in your Public and then just use the old way ex;
(in your controller actions):

```
                include 'PHPExcel.php';
                include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

                $myobject = new PHPExcel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally I added a "\" on the line where PHPExcel_IOFactory uses In Controller Class:

```
public function reporteauditoriaAction()
{
    $objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Alejin Wbn');
    $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
    $objWriter->save("pruebaPhpExcelZend.xlsx"); 
    //$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
    //unset($objPHPExcel);
    $consulta= "Reporte Auditoria, Reconocio los Archivos";
    $vista = new ViewModel(array( "consulta"=>$consulta));
    return $vista;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and i solved it update the composer and in my project folder phpoffice saved inside the vendor module (not in lib).
And adding "\" on the PHPExcel_IOFactory whereever you seen.