# PHPExcel not working in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpexcel

I followed this link - [PHPExcel integration into Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742706/phpexcel-integration-into-zend-framework)

Copied files/folder as mentioned -

```
> /library
>     /PHPExcel
>     /PHPExcel.php
```

And added in application.ini file-

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "PHPExcel_"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "PHPExcel"
```

Now under `mysite\application\modules\admin\controllers` and in `MysiteController.php` I am using this, in this manner -

```
public function getExcelDataAction() 
{
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:D1');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Swapnesh');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $filename = "my-data-sheet".".xlsx";
    $objWriter->save($filename);    
}
```

Following error occurred -

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel' not found in C:\webserver\mysite\application\modules\admin\controllers\MysiteController.php on line 526
```

Let me know how can i make it working in `Zend`( beginner in zend)

Comment: can you try `$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel_PHPExcel();`

Comment: @NandakumarV Sure let me gave it a try

Comment: @NandakumarV sorry not working ..throwing this class not exists PHPExcel_PHPExcel

Comment: is the `PHPExcel` added in the included paths. * use `print_r(get_include_path())`

Comment: if the class does not have the naming convention (FOLDER_CLASS) than include it by your own: `include PATH_TO_LIB.'/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';`

Comment: or write your own autoloader and push it into Zend's one with `pushAutoloader`. [http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html)

Comment: @redreggae thx it worked for me using autoloader technique :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPExcel class not found in Zend Autoloader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816426/phpexcel-class-not-found-in-zend-autoloader)

Comment: Actually, it looks like the structure of PHPExcel has changed since that answer I referenced. But the general technique of pushing a custom autoloader onto the ZF autoloader stack still applies for libs that are not PSR-0 compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my implementation PHPExcel was the last thing to fire so I didn't need Zends own autoloader anymore after initiation PHPExcel and thus created my own workaround like this.

//In controller, I call a norlmal Zend Model

```
$excelModel = new Application_Model_Excel();
```

//The exelmodel (which lives in Application/Models/Excel.php) looks like this

```
<?php
spl_autoload_unregister(array('Zend_Loader_Autoloader','autoload'));
require_once('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
class Application_Model_Excel extends PHPExcel
{


}
?>
```

This is most certainly not the best way to do it, but works without a hitch in my app

Comment: Thanks for another solution..I will surely try this one also +1 for your efforts.